# Web Platform installer and sql express database setup

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, sql-server-express, web-platform-installer

I tried to install Amplifeeder today with the Web Platform Installer.

When I arrived at the database setup I had to fill out some informations like "db admin user/password" and user username/password.

Using SQL Express I do not have any username/password (neither admin or user). How should I be able to install applications with the WPI and SQL Express 2008 ?

Basically I had this error while trying to install in the logs :

```
DownloadManager Error: 0 : MS Deploy exception: Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentClientServerException: The database 'AmpliFeederDB' could not be created. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally achieved this by command line and reg fixes.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer
```

`LoginMode` must be 2

restart SQL Server Express service.

Then : 
In command line :

```
sqlcmd -E -S .\SQLEXPRESS (will login with windows authentication mode)

1) ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '<new_password>'
2) GO
1) ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE
2) GO
```

It should do the trick to install the applications after.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the only way I could make it work was by using the command line utility 'WebPICmd.exe' located in the application folder.

You do need a strong password because it uses a regular expression to verify.

All seemed OK, I was able to access the DB thru OSQL and also Management Studio, had no problems with logons, had both authentications enabled, TCP/IP and named pipes. yet nothing worked... It seems to be some kind of a bug....

Thry it like his:

WebPICmd.exe /Install /Application:"Joomla"

Answer (score 1):

When you install SQL Server Express for the first time, you would have had option to select authentication mode, where you would select MIXED mode authentication and provide admin authentication details.

Comment: I did select Windows authentication mode. Must I absolutely use mixed ?

Comment: Or try using windows admin details as follows
<Domain>\Username
******
or
<ComputerName>\Username
*******

Answer (score 1):

Well, the SQL Server Management Studio Express provides a more sustainable solution. See this link, without having to fiddle with registry keys & running commands:

http://www.knowledgesutra.com/forums/topic/61695-resolving-cant-login-to-sqlexpress-using-sa-account/

Comment: Nice link, but the solution is for the 2005 version and I found it hard to install 'Management Studio Express for SQL Server Express 2008', hence I preferred Erick's solution.